# Посоветуйте пошаговую инструкцию для создания простейшего http-сервиса

Tags: http, api, get, веб-сервер

Хотелось бы найти видео или руководство, где от начала до конца разбирается, как создать webAPI, пусть даже самое примитивное, обрабатывающее единственный GET-запрос.

Пожелания к инструкции:

1) Упор на то, как вообще устроен сервис. Какие файлы нужно создавать, и в какие папки на хостинге нужно класть эти файлы, чтобы алгоритм, содержащийся в этих файлах запускался при получении сервисом запроса

2) Желательно чтобы это был GET-запрос, который в ответ на логин и пароль выдает токен. Так как такой запрос достаточно распространённый, идеальный случай найти готовый шаблон такого сервиса

В интернете примеров много, но они как будто для тех, кто уже делал API.

Например тут: https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340 вроде как написано для начинающих, но даны фрагменты кода, судя по всему на javascript, а куда вставлять эти фрагменты - непонятно.

То есть нужно что-то типа Создание API от нуля для тех, кто это никогда не делал. Я понимаю, что способов написания много, нужен просто один, но пошаговый и доскональный пример.

Comment: Для создания API не нужно знать "как создавать API". Так как вы спрашиваете видимо о web API (их вообще десятки видов), то для его создания вам нужно знать: принципы протокола http, язык javascript и его работу в браузерах (на среднем уровне), какой либо серверный язык (php, javascript, java, и т.п.). Когда вы их знаете - вы сами решите куда в конкретно вашем случае какие файлы класть. Общей инструкции,  "создайте файл, положите его туда", быть не может. Так что начинайте с изучения языков и web-технологий

Comment: Так вот есть ли какое-то руководство или лучше видео, где всё это показывается, а не так, что обрывочные фрагменты работы? Запросы GET, POST я понимаю, javascript тоже (правда, со словарем). Мне нужно сделать простое API, с единственным запросом GET, на входе логин и пароль, а на выходе - токен. Это настолько распространённый случай, что может быть для него готовые шаблоны существуют?

Comment: а к какой информации вы хотите предоставить доступ ?

Comment: Всё-таки определитесь с серверным языком, на котором будете делать API.

Comment: _даны фрагменты кода, судя по всему на javascript_ - вы бы хоть до прочитали... На PHP там пример.

Comment: Нужен простой сервис, который выдаёт токен при наличии регистрации, то есть санкционирует работу в приложении пользователем

Comment: API от обычного Web приложения отличается только тем, что серверный скрипт вместо html клиенту отдает что то более простое - текст или json. А так как вы не оговорили в каком формате хотите передавать запрос на сервер, то это может быть например post с обычными параметрами формы. Так что берете любой php который умеет делать авторизацию (как будто пользователь заполнил форму с логином и паролем) и вместо странички "вы авторизованы" печатает токен (ну или его же в json). И в любом случае вам надо учить какой нибудь "серверный" язык

Comment: Я собираюсь передавать текст на сервер через Retrofit, это библиотека для Android Studio

Comment: открываем первое что дает гугл по запросу "Retrofit", читаем "_URL parameter replacement and query parameter support_". Все отлично, он умеет передавать параметры как в url GET и как параметры формы для POST. Значит на серверной стороне как и сказал, это ни чем не отличается от того, как пользователь сам в форму ввел логин и пароль

Comment: Хорошо, а есть какой-нибудь готовый пример, как это реализуется? Ведь понятно, что я не изучу PHP за 2 недели, но хотя бы освоить ту его часть, которая нужна именно для этого, и лучше - на каких-нибудь исходниках

Comment: Судя по вашему профилю, вы пишете под Android, используя Android Studio. Какой язык вы используете? Вероятно, Java. Вот на этом языке и пишите API. | Или неужто вы всё делаете визуально, мышекликаньем? Ну, тогда в голову приходит Swagger (гугл в помощь): можно декларативно описать желаемый API, потом сгенерировать код (как сервера, так и клиента) на разных языках.

Comment: Ну так вот мне и нужна вводная информация о том, как компилировать API, например в Android Studio. Понимаете, я всю жизнь писал только клиентскую часть: посылал запросы и получал ответы. А теперь возникла необходимость написать серверную часть. И я спрашиваю у народа, есть ли какое-нибудь видео или руководство, где подробно и в деталях для начинающих рассказывается, как создать пусть даже самый простой сервис, например, с единственным GET-запросом. Например разбирается то, где входная процедура, в которую сервис заходит, получая GET запрос от клиента и т.д. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Ну так отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, какой язык используете, IDE тоже можно указать. Поймите: вам не API нужно компилировать, а код на каком-либо языке.

Comment: Так я уже откорректировал, а модеры не снимают свою метку. Среда разработки - желательно блокнот (соответственно язык PHP или javascript), чтобы ничего не устанавливать. Можно и Android Studio, как в этом примере: https://youtu.be/9w--Nn1UNRc, только я всё время раньше думал, что Android Studio для мобильных приложений, но как этот парень из видео делает сервис - я не понимаю. Может кто подскажет, что надо выбирать в меню, чтобы создать такой проект, как у него.